# Function call not working with 'click' event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function-calls

I'm having issues with having a function execute with the click event handler. If I get rid of the function numberCheck() and post the code directly into the event handler, then it works fine. Am I missing something basic here?

Here is my code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
var scopedVariable;
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
function numberCheck() {
$(this).closest('#outsideContainer').find('.hotter').addClass('hideStuff');
 $(this).closest('#outsideContainer').find('.colder').addClass('hideStuff');
var guess = $(this).closest('#guessContainer').find('.value').val();
    if( +guess === number)
    {
    $(this).closest('#outsideContainer').find('.gotIt').removeClass('hideStuff');
    }
    else {
        $(this).closest('#guessContainer').find('.value').val('Please guess again');
        if(Math.abs(guess - number) < Math.abs(scopedVariable - number)) {
            $(this).closest('#outsideContainer').find('.hotter').removeClass('hideStuff');
            }
        else if(Math.abs(guess - number) > Math.abs(scopedVariable - number)) {
            $(this).closest('#outsideContainer').find('.colder').removeClass('hideStuff');
            }
        scopedVariable = guess;
        } 


}

$('.query').on('click', function() {

        numberCheck();
  }); 
 });
```

here is my HTML if needed:

```
<body>
    <div id="outsideContainer">
    <div id="guessContainer">
        <h3> Guess a number between 1 and 10 </h3>

        <input id="txtfield" name="txtfield" type="text" class="value"/><br>
        <input type = "submit" class="query" />

    </div>
    <div id="guessShow">
        <p class="hotter hideStuff" > Getting Hotter!! </p>
        <p class="colder hideStuff"> Getting Colder, BRRR!!! </p>
        <p class="gotIt hideStuff"> Awesome! You have guessed the number </p>
    </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

Any help for this is much appreciated.

Comment: I supose `$(this)` is out of scope when inside a new function.

Comment: please don't forget to mention the framework when you use one. (corrected)

Comment: Yeah either replace `$(this)` with the actual element in the HTML, or pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 5):

Try passing `this` to your function (`numberCheck(this)`) and then name the parameter in your function something else and change the instances of `this` in the function to that name, like so:

```
function numberCheck(submitButton) {
    $(submitButton).closest('#outsideContainer').find('.hotter').addClass('hideStuff');
    [...]
}

$('.query').on('click', function() {
    numberCheck(this);
});
```

Comment: This worked! I didn't realize $(this) is out of scope inside a new function. Good to know

Answer (score 2):

Instead of executing the function, pass that function as an input parameter to the event click.

```
$('.query').on('click',numberCheck);
```

On this way, you are passing the callBack as a input parameter, and your function gets access to the object, where the event click was fired.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   var that = this;
   // the rest of your code
```

and use `that` instead of `this` inside of the inner function.

Answer (score 0):

I think `this` is a problem, you should use it as a parameter.
Please try this: (I use `.click()` instead of `.on()`)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
var scopedVariable;
var number = Math.floor(Math.random()*11);
function numberCheck($this) {
    $this.closest('#outsideContainer').find('.hotter').addClass('hideStuff');
    $this.closest('#outsideContainer').find('.colder').addClass('hideStuff');
    var guess = $this.closest('#guessContainer').find('.value').val();
        if( +guess === number)
        {
        $this.closest('#outsideContainer').find('.gotIt').removeClass('hideStuff');
        }
        else {
            $this.closest('#guessContainer').find('.value').val('Please guess again');
            if(Math.abs(guess - number) < Math.abs(scopedVariable - number)) {
                $this.closest('#outsideContainer').find('.hotter').removeClass('hideStuff');
                }
            else if(Math.abs(guess - number) > Math.abs(scopedVariable - number)) {
                $this.closest('#outsideContainer').find('.colder').removeClass('hideStuff');
                }
            scopedVariable = guess;
            } 


}

$('.query').click(function() {
    //console.log($(this).html());
    numberCheck($(this));
});
```

And this a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GD6Mn/). I hope this help.